# JavaScript Bundling Not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have refered https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html
for javascript bundling:

After doing all the step i have check Network in browser and it seems found all the js loaded instead of bundle js.

First time:

[image]

**After redeploying:**

[image]

Comment: what happened when you try to redeploy static view files?

Comment: @magefms i have redeployed and this directory become blanks. please see SS

Comment: Ensure you're running in production mode. Ensure the folder permissions are correct.